# Python, iterating between 2 lists of lists, seeing if values in one list are similar to values in the other and extracting them

Tags: python, list, iterator, iteration, nested-lists

I have two list of lists containing cartesian coordinates:

```
    LBCoord = [[1195,456],[1324,674],[5644,687],[4679,654]] #very long list
    CoreCoord = [[1145,466],[1524,644],[5664,657],[4479,654]] #very long list
```

I want to iterate through these two lists, seeing if any of the two sets of coordinates in both x (LBCoord[n][0]) and y (LBCoord[n][1]), fall within a user determined x and y range. (To clarify, the sets of coordinates that I am searching for need to be within an x range, and a y range of each other within any position in LBCoord and CoreCoord)

i.e.

```
    #user determined x and y ranges
    xRange = 3
    yRange = 5
    LBCoord = [[1000,400],[1324,674],[5644,687],[4679,654]] #very long list
    CoreCoord = [[1145,466],[1524,644],[5664,657],[997,395]] #very long
```

If LBCoord contains the coordinates [1000,400] and CoreCoord contains [997,395], I want the program to print out these sets of coordinates (as they are within the xRange and yRange) and to continue running.

I've tried using nested for loops, but these end up pulling out duplicates/permutations of the coordinates which is an issue, as they are difficult to deal with when implementing in a jython script.

Another issue to contend with, is this needs to be executed with a script that is compatible with Python 2.5, and fiji, therefore some imported tools do not work.

Any help would be appreciated!

Many thanks,

Ben

Comment: What you call `xRange` and `yRange` are in fact the acceptable _distance_ between the corresponding LBCoord/CoreCoord ?

Comment: so, your xRange and yRange will be in the thousands not in the digits right? you want to get a list of all coordinates that fall within the x and y range from the lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple filter over the cartesian product of the two lists would produce what you want but the run time may be unacceptable. Lets start with that:

```
match_pairs = []
for current_lb_coord in LBCoord:
    for current_core_coord in CoreCoord:
        if abs(current_lb_coord[0] - current_core_coord[0]) <= xRange
            and abs(current_lb_coord[1] - current_core_coord[1]) <= yRange:
            match_pairs.append((current_lb_coord, current_core_coord))
```

This creates a list of tuples with the `LBCoord` first and the `CoreCoord` second. However it could take a very long time to run as you need to do a comparison for every pair in both lists - so it has `O(m * n)` complexity.

The next thing is to try and optimize it. Since you really have two filters, you know that if the variation in one is too great then it doesn't matter if the other is a good match. Given this you can sort the two lists by the x coordinate. You can then operate over both lists, looking for points that overlap well.

Sorting the list takes `O(n log n)` time. Once that is done you should be able to run through both lists in parallel once (it's a little more complex than this in practice) so this should reduce the time taken somewhat. The complexity comes from the fact that you can have multiple matches for a given entry.

In the following code I am going to pretend that only the x coordinate matters. You should take this code and enhance it to include the y coordinate. The fundamental process of sorting the list and then operating on both should get you a good speedup:

```
sorted_lb_coords = sorted(LBCoord)
sorted_core_coords = sorted(CoreCoord)
lb_index = core_index = 0
match_pairs = []

while lb_index < len(sorted_lb_coords) and core_index < len(sorted_core_coords):
    current_lb = sorted_lb_coords[lb_index]
    current_core = sorted_core_coords[core_index]

    # Remember I am only considering x
    if abs(current_lb - current_core) < limit:
        match_pairs.append((current_lb, current_core))

    # This part may also be more complex if you want all available matches.
    # You could run through all the current_core entries till one was out
    # of range and then reset the current_core index and increment the
    # current_lb index.
    if current_lb < current_core:
        current_lb = current_lb + 1
    else:
        current_core = current_core + 1
```

So this example is heavily simplified, but hopefully it can show you an improved approach for this matching.

Comment: The speed is more than acceptable, thank-you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) and [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) :

```
>>> filter(lambda x : abs(x[0][0]-x[1][0])==145 and abs(x[0][3]-x[1][4])==66 , zip(LBCoord,CoreCoord))
[([1000, 400], [1145, 466])]
```

Comment: @BenMargetts Your welcome if you find this answer helpful you can tell this to community with vote or accept it

Comment: zip doesn't pair every entry in one list with the other, it only pairs ones at equal indexes. This means that you would not find all matches.